# What is the word for someone who is easily obsessed over

Tags: meaning

We are wanting to know what the word is for someone who has a trait that can be easily obsessed over

Comment: [Charismatic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charismatic)

Comment: It depends on the type of trait. Having a lovely voice is quite different than having no nose … (So, the trait also determines the type of obsession.)

Comment: Captivating? Mesmerizing?

Comment: Outstanding, but I agree with Jason Bassford,  it depends on the trait.

Comment: *Spellbinding*, *charming*, *adorable*? Please add an example sentence illustrating how you would use the word you're seeking.

Comment: @RichardKayser - Someone with warts on their face is "adorable"?

Comment: Trying to understand your comment has made it clear to me that there are (at least) two ways to interpret the question: (1) someone has a trait that *they themselves* can easily obsess over (e.g., "horror, my left eye is smaller than my right eye"), and (2) someone has a trait that *others* can easily obsess over (e.g., "he is adorable"). I was reading the OP's question the second way. Only the OP can clarify.

Comment: How about _enchanting_?

Comment: Who is doing the obsessing here? The person with the trait, or an outside observer? Also, as @Jason Bassford suggested, is it a positive or negative trait? The answer kinda depends on the context.

Comment: @RichardKayser A positive trait does not necessarily equate to "adorable". Would you call Einstein's intellect adorable? (Although I suspect we're both saying the same thing and just coming up with examples for particular contexts.)

Comment: @JasonBassford I agree with your parenthetical. I'm voting to close based on the questioner's failure to provide an example sentence and to respond to other comments above.